# Mysql ZeosLib Delphi XE3

Tags: mysql, delphi, zeos

I would like to know how I can save a query in memory to display in DBgrid,

my current application is using :

TZConnection > TZquery > DataSource > DBgrid

works fine but the problem here is, after a call ZConnection.disconnect the dbgrid is cleaned

i want to disconnect TZConnection immediately after finish the query because most MySQL databases have an limited numbers of user connected simultaneously.

Comment: I'd copy the whole data to a TClientDataSet or TkbmMemTable(?) but since you kill the connection, why not display data in a TListView or TVirtualStringTree?

Comment: Can you put some examples to Copy whole data to the ClientDataSet, i try that but with no sucess.

Comment: @Rebless it's a two stage operation(or 1 if you setup the client data set in design time), the two stage is: 1) for each "field" in your query, create a field in "client data set", 2) for each *record* in query, copy content to "client data set", really easy and straight forward, it will be a very nice exercise, have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the TDataSetProvider to transfer your Query data into the ClientDataSet. That component does everything for you.

Put the following components on your DataModule, and link them accordingly:

```
TZQuery <- TDataSetProvider <- TClientDataSet <- TDataSource

TDataSource.DataSet := TClientDataSet;
TCLientDataSet.ProviderName := TDataSetProvider;
TDataSetProvider.DataSet := TZQuery;
```

After that, just call the `TClientDataSet.Open` method, and the data are transfered automaticaly into the TClientDataSet. With `TClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates`, you can push back the data into your database.

I use that technic with firebird (TIBQuery).

Here are some information about ClientDataSets:
[A ClientDataSet in Every Database Application](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28876)
[Delphi In Depth: ClientDataSet book](http://www.jensendatasystems.com/cdsbook/)
[Building Applications With ClientDataSet and InterBase Express](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27653)

Comment: Thx for your help but, that doesn't work for me, 

TZQuery > TDataSetProvider - ok, i can set the TDataSetProvider property "DataSet" to TZQuery 

but now there's no link between TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet


can you wrote a little example for me ?

Comment: See edit above. You can connect them in the ObjectInspector at design time.